# Interesting property of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let we have an integer number $m$ such that $p \mid m \implies (p^2-1) \mid m$  for any prime divisor $p$ of $m.$ Prove that for such $m$ we have $F_{n+m}=F_{m} \mod m $  for any $n>1.$

Any ideas  how to prove it? I checked  it for $m=24, 48 $ but cant prove in general.

Comment: It looks like an hybrid between the Von-Staudt-Clausen theorem for Bernoulli numbers and the usual properties of Pisano periods. Definitely interesting.

Comment: I think it boils down to the well-known fact that for every prime $p\neq 5$, the period of the sequence $\{F_n\pmod{p}\}_{n\geq 0}$ is a divisor of $p^2-1$.